# insert data from database to textbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, textbox

I have 2 textboxes and 2 labels.

label: UserID & ACCType.

textbox: Email & Password.

I want to find data from the textboxes and then insert data from the database into the 2 labels.

so, in other words, I would like to collect the email and password in the textboxes. from this information, i want to then insert the ID and AccountType in the labels. what am I doing wrong?

```
        protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string UID = UserID.Text;
        string AType = AccType.Text;
        string Email = Email.Text;
        string Password = Password.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=sql2016.fse.network;Initial Catalog=db_1518393_fse_rec; User ID=user_db_1518393_fse_rec; Password=P@55word;";

        Int32 verify;
        string query1 = "Select * from Accounts where Email='" + Email.Text + "' and Password='" + Password.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        con.Open();
        verify = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        if (verify > 0)
        {
            //successful
            ErrorMessage.Text += "Logging in...";
            //Response.Redirect("succesful.aspx");

            //display User ID & Account Type


            string query2 = "INSERT * from Accounts where Email='" + Email.Text + "' and Password='" + Password.Text + "' + ID + AccountType";
            //string query2 = "Select Email, Password, ID, AccountType from Accounts(Email, Password, ID, AccountType) " + "Values('" + Email + "', '" + Password + "', '" + UID + "', '" + AType + "')";

        }
        else
        {
            //unsuccessful
            //Response.Redirect("unsuccesful.aspx", true);
            ErrorMessage.Text += "Email or Password incorrect! Please try again.";
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is wrong? Is there an error? If so, what error?

Comment: @cubrr the ID and AccountType aren't displaying in the labels.

Comment: `string query2 = "INSERT * from Accounts where Email='" + Email.Text + "' and Password='" + Password.Text + "' + ID + AccountType";` => `INSERT INTO Accounts(Email, Password) Values ('" + Email.Text + "', '" + Password.Text + "')";`  by the way, you should use parameters to prevent sql injection .

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-read the syntax of the INSERT statement. While at it look also for Sql Injection Vulnerability

Comment: Your insert query is wrongly written

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
    string query2 = "INSERT * from Accounts where Email='" + Email.Text + "' and Password='" + Password.Text + "' + ID + AccountType";
```

should be like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

as showing in W3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider here...

First, as many people noticed (and always will here on SO), **NEVER** concatenate strings for commnand text. Instead, user parameters, like this:

```
string query1 = "Select * from Accounts where Email=@Email and Password=@Password ";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password.Text;
```

Second, you are using `ExecuteScalar` which only return number of affected rows. Instead, you should read data with `DataReader`. Something like this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
verify = reader.HasRows;

if (verify)
{
    ErrorMessage.Text += "Logging in...";
    reader.Read();

    this.lblUserId.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
    //read other data into other labels
}

con.Close();
```

third, you `INSERT` syntax is wrong and should be like this:

```
string query2 = @"
INSERT INTO Accounts 
    (Email, Password, ID, AccountType)
VALUES
    (@Email, @Password, @ID, @AccountType)
";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = /* some ID textbox or what ever */;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccountType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = /* some value for acc type */;
```

... and fourth:

why do you enter account data into table after user successfully logged in?

Comment: i wanted to enter data into the labels when successfully logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to update the labels after collecting email and password from the textboxes which i guess can be achieved using the 'query1', if the Account table of yours contain the field 'UserId' and 'AccountType'. You should use DataReader instead of ExecuteScalar for verification and reading of data from db and update the labels with UserId and AccountType. Following can be the hypothetical answer of yours:-

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
if(dr.HasRows)
{
  //if email and password is okay
  while(dr.Read())
  {
   //successful
   ErrorMessage.Text += "Logging in...";
   //Response.Redirect("succesful.aspx");

   //display User ID & Account Type
   UserId.Text = (string)dr["userid"];
   AccType.Text = (string)dr["accounttype"];
  }
 }
 else{
    //unsuccessful
    //Response.Redirect("unsuccesful.aspx", true);
    ErrorMessage.Text += "Email or Password incorrect! Please try again.";
 }
```

And Finally, I have no idea on why you trying to insert any data to the Account table after logging in. I mean you should update some field on your table instead of inserting a new row into the table.

Comment: Can you give a more detail on errors you got, because my code was just a hint on how you can use it on your main code or you may update your post here with your current code